Does the CarPlay network type indicator font weight indicate anything?
Sometimes the network type indicator near the top left of the CarPlay display is in a normal font and other times it is in a bold font. Here are two screenshots from today:


This is an iPhone 15 Pro Max (A2849) running iOS 17.5.1 (21F90) connected to a 2023 BMW iX wirelessly.
Is this meant to indicate anything in particular or perhaps simply a display glitch?

I can barely tell the difference when looking at your images.  If you wouldn't have told me the text was bold I never would've noticed.  Making small, almost imperceptible, changes like that is not something Apple would use as an indicator for a change.
